# Difference between single quote and double single quotes in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two queries, first one is the regular `SELECT` and the other one is an `EXEC` query as what I mentioned below:

1. `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] = 'test'`

and

2. `EXEC(' SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] = ''test'' ')`

as for the results, I tried to execute both queries in sql server 2008 and i was given the exact same outputs, if both queries return the same output then what's the purpose of the single quote and double single quotes in sql?

Comment: Careful, 2 single quotes isn't a double quote.

Comment: Doubled single quotes are normally used for quoting, e.g. `insert into foo (f1) values ('O''brian')`

Comment: I have this feeling that your actual `EXEC` is `EXEC( 'SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] = ''test''' )` And surely there you can see the difference. When you have a single quote in a string literal you have to escape it with a second single quote: So `variable='this is a ''test'''` sets `variable` to `this is a 'test'`

Comment: oh yeah sorry my bad it's actually `EXEC( 'SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] = ''test''' )` @JNevill